# "Plugin not found for prefix" error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jetty

In Eclipse I imported a maven-based project which uses maven jetty plugin.  If I run `mvn jetty:run` from command line, everything works fine.  If I add a run configuration in Eclipse and try to run it, I get the error message:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/eugene/.m2/repository), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

In the Eclipe run configuration, I use:

- Base directory: `${project_loc}`
- Goal: `jetty:run`
- Maven Runtime: External

I read the [[Help1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException)] page.  I don't have pluginGroup settings in maven configuration files, but I have the jetty plugin mentioned in pom.xml, so I guess everything should be fine (especially because everything works in command-line).  I tried to "Run as > Maven clean" in Eclipse before executing the jetty run configuration, but it didn't help.  Project compiles and passes all tests, only jetty:run does not work in Eclipse.

Please help, I'm an Eclipse & Maven newbie.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use full plugin name `maven-jetty-plugin`?

Comment: Do you mean using it as the goal prefix `maven-jetty-plugin:run`? It does not work neither in Eclipse nor in the command line

Comment: By the way, I found a solution.  I added my own answer below.

Answer (score 20):

It does not work for me from command-line either.

Can you check if it works after adding the following in `settings.xml` as [documented](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin)?

```
<pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.mortbay.jetty</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

Also note that there are two different versions of the plugin - the older [maven jetty plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) and the newer [jetty maven plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin).

Comment: In the project the older one (maven jetty plugin) is used.  Providing settings.xml did not work, but I found the cause of the problem (I'll now add an answer)

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html, Maven uses `jetty-maven-plugin` as an example to show a customized settings.xml.

Comment: All Codehaus services have been terminated, links are broken.

Answer (score 10):

I met this problem too, an easier way to solve this is to edit your `pom.xml`, add following plugin:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.8.v20121106</version>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

**Note**:

1. `jetty-maven-plugin` is used for jetty version 7 and above, if you want jetty version 6, you should use `maven-jetty-plugin`
2. for the version, you may want to have a look at [here](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/) and [here](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/maven-jetty-plugin/) for your desired version's full name.

Answer (score 4):

I apologize for wasting your time.  Now I looked through maven warnings which appeared in Eclipse console after I ran the run configuration.  I noticed

> [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for Plugin [org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin]: null

so it became obvious why it couldn't recognize `jetty:` prefix.  Couple of lines above I saw a bunch of warnings about missing plugin versions.  So I added a version specification for the jetty plugin (`<version>` entry in pom.xml) and it solved the problem.  I forgot a common rule that if something breaks the first thing to check is warnings you get.

Comment: org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.0.4.20130625 is the latest coordinates, docs are here -> http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html

Answer (score 4):

I've got this issue in eclipse after importing an appengine project.

The target:

```
mvn appengine:devserver
```

The error:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/averasko/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

The problem was in the incorrect **base directory** in the eclipse **run configuration**. When maven does not see a *pom.xml* file and is asked to run some non-standard target if fails like this as it don't know anything about the plugin that defines the target.

The solution is to correct the **base directory** to wherever your *pom.xml* file resides.

Answer (score 3):

if you following this tutorial:

> http://tapestry.apache.org/creating-the-skeleton-application.html

don't forget to follow this one crucial instruction:

> Change into the newly created directory, and execute the command: