# Missing Maven Plugin Jetty

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-3

I am having trouble folowing this http://hrycan.com/2012/03/28/primefaces-lazy-loading-datatable-for-jsf2/

It says I should just run

```
mvn jetty:run
```

but I keep on encountering this error.

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found
for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.m
aven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\MyRepo), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)]
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.r
```

I used Maven 3 here.

Any thoughts?

ADD:

From the link, it has this already in the pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.1.v20110908</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Plugin not found for prefix" error in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414075/plugin-not-found-for-prefix-error-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you add the plugin to the pom.xml? A quick google search found this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Found here:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/jetty-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to add this.. it has this plugin

Comment: Did not work "as is" for me. I had to set the groupId line as `<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>`. I also had to fully qualify the plugin the first time I run maven: `mvn org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:run`. This is hardly as simple as Dariop answer seems to imply (at least for complete n00bs like me).

Comment: please see the instructions by @Doug

Comment: the new groupId is `org.eclipse.jetty`

Answer (score 32):

The instructions at (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html) say to put the version as ${project.version} which is wrong! Also, the older documentation has the groupId set to org.codehaus.mojo it should be set to org.eclipse.jetty.

I added a real version from the jetty repo (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/) and changed the groupId.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is the only option that worked for me, maybe the official answer is outdated?

Comment: @Doug How did you find the correct jetty version of the jetty plugin

Comment: @Diode I searched the mvn repository: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty.

Comment: @Doug, thanks this worked for me, but I also had to add org.eclipse.jetty as a pluginGroup in /etc/maven/settings.xml (I am using Debian)

Answer (score 4):

Check if it works after adding the following in settings.xml as documented.

```xml
<pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.mortbay.jetty</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

Also note that there are two different versions of the plugin - the older maven-jetty-plugin and the newer jetty-maven-plugin.
<sub>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7416789/1429387)</sub>

Comment: Answers to the duplicate of this Question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/27737918/1357094) have more details for the settings.xml

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are executing command 'mvn jetty:run', from inside your project directory. If you will listed the current directory you should see the pom.xml.

If you are in not in your project and running 'mvn jetty:run', will get Error "Missing Maven Plugin Jetty"

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
            <configuration>
                <stopKey>todostop</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Hope it will help

Comment: What does "If you will listed the current directory you should see the pom.xml" mean?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. I started `jetty:run` from within Eclipse using a "Maven Build" run configuration.

The problem was, within my Maven Build run configuration, the "base directory" (i.e. the working directory used by the mvn executable) was set incorrectly. Setting the base directory to the directory containing the `pom.xml` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your version is wrong. Try

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>9.2.6.v20141205</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the plugin part you should be in the pom.xml directory to make starting the jetty command.