# maven - "Plugin not found for prefix" error while running fortify via Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, fortify

[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'fortify' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Plugin not found for prefix" error in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414075/plugin-not-found-for-prefix-error-in-eclipse)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Unfortunately it doesn't help

Comment: is fortify plugin declared in the concerned `pom.xml` file either in `pluginManagement/plugins` or `plugins` section?

Comment: Hey @Anand did you resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding pluginGroup in settings.xml

```
<pluginGroup>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</pluginGroup>
```